# Any way to restrict empty fields from email templates

Tags: apex, soql, community, email, email-template

Hi friends is there any way to restrict empty fields from email templates when sending email to users with workflow or any other.

I have a workflow.Whenever any record meets the criteria it will sent an email to specified users.So,in my template there are so many fields.sometimes some of the fields will be blank.So it showing some space in between.So,i don't want user to get spaces in mail.

Comment: Please be more clear, what do you mean by restrict empty fields?

Comment: I updated my question @Frederik Witte

Answer (score 3):

You can use IF statements in your email templates:

```
{!IF(NOT(ISBLANK(Object.Field)), "Field Label: " & Object.Field, "")}
```

Alternatively, you can use Visualforce templates and use the "rendered" attribute, like this:

```
<apex:outputField value="{!Object.Field}" rendered="{!NOT(ISBLANK(Object.Field))}" />
```

Comment: `{!BLANKVALUE(Object.Field,'valueIfBlank')}` can also be used in appropriate circumstances